# C++ How to select class via optional typedef, using SFINAE or whatever

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11, sfinae

The user customizes a library template class by defining a class specifying the desired options. Call it a manifest. The idea is to have optional typedefs in the manifest. If the user's manifest contains a typedef for H, for example, I want the library code to use the indicated type as its "H". If there is no typedef in the user's manifest, the library will use a default.

I suspect there is an elegant way to do this by utilizing the new C++11 features, but I am coming up empty. I have a solution, based on the Wikipedia entry for SFINAE. It is ugly. It requires a new template function **has_typedef_H** for each new H. I am vaguely uneasy that it exploits the property that **0** can mean either the integer or a null pointer. Just seems too klugey.

Is there a better way? Preferably one that will work in VC++ 2010?

In the toy example there are five classes, H1, H2, and U0, U1, and U2.  H1 and H2 are examples of "helpers" for a library class L. H1 is the default. The U's are examples of user-defined classes. In the example, I omitted defining a library class L, just using the body of main() to select the H's based upon typedefs in the U's (or the lack thereof). subject of type H2.

```
struct H1{
    void operator() (){ std::cout << "H1" << std::endl;}
};

struct H2{
    void operator() (){ std::cout << "H2" << std::endl;}
};


struct default_H: public H1 {};

struct U2 {
    typedef H2 H;
};

struct U1 {
    typedef H1 H;
};

struct U0 {
};


template <typename T>
class has_typedef_H {

    typedef char no[false+1];
    typedef char yes[true+1];

    template 
    static yes& test(typename C::H*);

    template 
    static no& test(...);

public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(test(0))-1; 
};


template<typename U, bool >
struct type_H_B: public default_H{};

template<typename U>
struct type_H_B<U, true>: public U::H {};

template<typename U>
struct H_type: public type_H_B<U, has_typedef_H<U>::value> {};

int main() {

    H_type<U0> h0;
    H_type<U1> h1;
    H_type<U2> h2;

    // Prints H1 H1 H2
    h0();
    h1();
    h2();
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to provide a complex trait for each one of the nested types, that can be done a bit simpler.  [Here](http://ideone.com/Gd4rQ) is an example:

```
// Helper to map any type to void, needed by SFINAE below
template <typename T>
struct void_type {
    typedef void type;
};

// Selects a nested typedef or a default type D (using a macro to reduce boilerplate):
#define SELECT_NESTED_TYPE( TYPE )                                       \
template <typename T, typename D, typename _ = void>                     \
struct select_##TYPE{                                                    \
    typedef D type;                                                      \
};                                                                       \
template <typename T, typename D>                                        \
struct select_##TYPE<T, D, typename void_type<typename T::TYPE>::type> { \
    typedef typename T::TYPE type;                                       \
};                                                                      

SELECT_NESTED_TYPE( int_t );
SELECT_NESTED_TYPE( float_t );
//...
#undef SELECT_NESTED_TYPE

// Use
template <typename T>
class TheTemplate {
public:
   typedef typename select_int_t<T,int>::type int_t;
   typedef typename select_float_t<T,double>::type float_t;
   //....
};

// Test:
template <typename T, typename U> struct same_type {
   static const bool value = false;
};
template <typename T> struct same_type<T,T> {
   static const bool value = true;
};
struct test1 {
};
struct test2 {
   typedef long long int_t;
   typedef float float_t;
};
int main() {
   // test1 has the default typedefs
   assert(( same_type< TheTemplate<test1>::int_t, int>::value ));
   assert(( same_type< TheTemplate<test1>::float_t, double>::value ));
   // test2 has the ones in the type
   assert(( same_type< TheTemplate<test2>::int_t, long long>::value ));
   assert(( same_type< TheTemplate<test2>::float_t, float>::value ));
}
```

You can opt to provide a slightly simpler solution if the macro takes the default type to use and injects it in the default case (when the nested type is not defined). Admittedly, this requires the creation of the trait for each nested type, but the trait is just a couple of lines (and not too hard to define as a macro). Alternatively, if there is just a couple of potential typedefs you might be able to do without the extra boilerplate and use SFINAE directly on the destination type.

---

Completely different approach... if you can

If you can modify the types that are used in the libraries, then you can use a much simpler (although not so *cool* solution) by abusing inheritance. Create a base class that only holds the typedefs for the default types to be used, and have every user class derive from the class that offers the defaults. If the user wants to provide a better helper than the default they just need to provide the typedef. If they don't provide a typedef, lookup will find the default higher up the hierarchy:

```
struct default_helpers {
   typedef Helper1 helper1_t;
   typedef Helper2 helper2_t;
// ...
};
struct user_type_1 : default_helpers {
};
struct user_type_2 : default_helpers {
   typedef MyHelper helper1_t;           // I prefer this one...
};
int main() {
   assert( same_type< user_type1::helper1_t, default_helpers::helper1_t >::value );
   assert( !same_type< user_type2::helper1_t, default_helpers::helper1_t >::value );
   assert( same_type< user_type1::helper2_t, user_type2::helper2_t>::value );
}
```

Comment: Both of those solutions had occurred to me. I am not too keen on deriving from a class of defaults, because in the typical case the user will not even need to know about this stuff. The "manifest" will simply be a function-object that implements a multivariate function he wants to minimize. It has been so long since I used #macros that I had forgotten how to patch strings together. :-) Until the next set of cool features is added to C++ (C++25?), that might be the best. Maybe even after.

Comment: Another solution, and perhaps best, would be to use the type_traits way of doing it. That is non-invasive. But that answer does not solve the puzzle. I love puzzles.

Comment: @JiveDadson: The first approach *is* the `type_traits` way of doing it. The type is passed to a function that extract a trait, either a default type or the nested type... As of waiting for a new standard, if *static if* moves forward, that could be an option, but regarding this particular problem I don't think it would add anything other than a simpler syntax. Everything (I believe) that will be doable with *static if* in your problem can be resolved by abusing inheritance.

Comment: Ah ha. Light breaks over Dunderhead. The first version does avoid the klugery of using 0 for both an int and a null pointer, among other kluges, and it get's 'er done. Macros are old school, but so am I. I think I have convinced myself that the macro cannot be avoided, because one dares not type T::H except in sfinae-approved places. I think you have earned the coveted check mark.

Answer (score 0):

As David's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11876377/1053968) demonstrates, macros are going to help reduce the boilerplate code.  In my opinion, David's approach is superior, but it can be daunting to new meta-programmers.  As such, I want to help clear up some of the kludger by offering potential alternatives that may be slightly more explicit.

---

When the no-case is not a template, `0` is treated as an `int`:

```
template <typename T>
class has_typedef_H {
  typedef char no[1];
  typedef char yes[2];

  template <typename C>
  static yes& test(typename C::H*);

//  template <typename>
  static no& test(...);

public:
  static const bool value = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(test(0)); 
};
```

In this [example](http://ideone.com/w0ksZ):

- The yes-case is checked with `C` being deduced as an `int`, causing substituation to always fail with `int::H`.  This occurs before trying to use `0` as the value to represent a null pointer, as the function signature is still trying to be identified.
- The no-case is checked with its variadic argument being an `int`.  This is always selected since the yes-case always fails.

When the no-case is turned into a template function, there is no template argument to deduce, so the no-case is not a candidate.

```
template <typename T>
class has_typedef_H {
  typedef char no[1];
  typedef char yes[2];

  template <typename C>
  static yes& test(typename C::H*);

  template <typename>
  static no& test(...);

public:
  static const bool value = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(test(0)); 
};
```

As seen [here](http://ideone.com/9Iz9s), compilation fails because no matching function is found for `test(int)`.  Since deduction is not available for the no-case, the `test` call must explicitly select the specialization to be used:

```
template <typename T>
class has_typedef_H {
  typedef char no[1];
  typedef char yes[2];

  template <typename C>
  static yes& test(typename C::H*);

  template <typename>
  static no& test(...);

public:
   static const bool value = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(test<T>(0)); 
};
```

In this [example](http://ideone.com/9Fv1B), `0`'s dual representations does come into play.

- In the yes-case, `0` is checked as a valid initialization value for `T::H*`.
- In the no-case, `0` is an `int`.

In order to remove this dual representation, an `int` argument is added to the yes-case, and the `C::H*` argument is provided a default value of `NULL`.

```
template <typename T>
class has_typedef_H {
  typedef char no[1];
  typedef char yes[2];

  template <typename C>
  static yes& test(int, typename C::H* = NULL);

  template <typename>
  static no& test(...);

public:
  static const bool value = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(test<T>(1)); 
};
```

In this [example](http://ideone.com/Qo5lT), `test<T>()` can be called with any integer.

- In the yes-case, `1` is an `int`, and `C::H*` is explicitly set to `NULL`.
- In the no-case, `1` is also an `int`.

Because `sizeof` is evaluating an expression, and not executing it, it is possible to avoid passing a value known at compile time to `test`, as shown in [this](http://ideone.com/dMlZX) example.

```
template <typename T>
class has_typedef_H {
  typedef char no[1];
  typedef char yes[2];

  template <typename C>
  static yes& test(T*, typename C::H* = NULL);

  template <typename>
  static no& test(...);

  static T* t;

public:
  static const bool value = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(test<T>(t)); 
};
```

---

In the end, I have found the case using `0` to be fairly common in SFINAE.  With that said, if someone has an understanding of the approach using `0`, then the slightly more explicit approaches should not be difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach in addition to the good ones already posted here is to use the rarely used [dominance in virtual inheritance feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_%28C%2B%2B%29). I am showing a solution for two customizable types which can be extended for any number of N (subject to the number of base classes compiler limit):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A1 {};
struct A2 {};
struct B1 {};
struct B2 {};

struct DefaultManifest {
    typedef A1 A;
    typedef B1 B;
};

template<class T>
struct A_is : virtual DefaultManifest { typedef T A; };

template<class T>
struct B_is : virtual DefaultManifest { typedef T B; };


template<class T> struct Name { static char const* value; };
template<> char const* Name<A1>::value = "A1";
template<> char const* Name<A2>::value = "A2";
template<> char const* Name<B1>::value = "B1";
template<> char const* Name<B2>::value = "B2";

struct na1 : virtual DefaultManifest {};
struct na2 : virtual DefaultManifest {};

template<class T1 = na1, class T2 = na2>
struct Library {
    struct Manifest : T1, T2 {};
    typedef typename Manifest::A A;
    typedef typename Manifest::B B;

    Library() {
        printf("A is %s, B is %s\n", Name<A>::value, Name<B>::value);
    }
};

int main() {
    Library<> lib1;
    Library<A_is<A2> > lib2;
    Library<B_is<B2> > lib3;
    Library<A_is<A2>, B_is<B2> > lib4;
    Library<B_is<B2>, A_is<A2> > lib5;
}
```

The above outputs:

```
A is A1, B is B1
A is A2, B is B1
A is A1, B is B2
A is A2, B is B2
A is A2, B is B2
```